# Changing QGroupBox checkbox visual to an expander

Tags: python, pyside2

I've modified the behavior of a QGroupBox's checkbox to hide/show the children of the group, effectively acting as an expander. It's working great, but the only issue is that the default checkbox icon looks like it's for enabling/disabling the group, rather than expanding it. I'd like to replace it with an expander-style icon instead.

I found this post which almost answers my question (and ultimately I may end up having to use that solution): [Change PySide QGroupBox checkbox image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155287/change-pyside-qgroupbox-checkbox-image). The problem is that the answer provided there suggests using custom checkbox images, whereas I want to use the built-in OS-specific expander, like the one in QTreeView, which looks like this on my PC:
[image: QTreeView expanders]

Is this even possible? Are expanders considered a stylized checkbox or something else entirely? I'm fairly new to Qt so I'm not very familiar with how styles are handled. Is this something that I would be able to query for, and if so, would it even be compatible with QCheckBox styles? There isn't much I could find about expanders on the QTreeView documentation page aside from just enabling/disabling them, and I'm currently attempting to dig through the QTreeView.cpp source code to figure out how they work.

**Update**

Going off of eyllanesc's answer, I'm getting closer to a solution but I'm having some issues overriding methods of QProxyStyle. I'm attempting to do something like the following:

```
class GroupBoxExpanderStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._replaceCheckboxWithExpander = False

    def drawComplexControl(self, control, option, painter, widget):
        try:
            if control == QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_GroupBox and widget.isCheckable():
                self._replaceCheckboxWithExpander = True
            super().drawComplexControl(control, option, painter, widget)
        finally:
            self._replaceCheckboxWithExpander = False

    def drawPrimitive(self, element, option, painter, widget):
        if element == QtWidgets.QStyle.PE_IndicatorCheckBox and self._replaceCheckboxWithExpander:
            indicatorBranchOption = ... # Set up options for drawing PE_IndicatorBranch
            super().drawPrimitive(QtWidgets.QStyle.PE_IndicatorBranch, indicatorBranchOption, painter, widget)
        else:
            super().drawPrimitive(element, option, painter, widget)
```

Something similar appears to have been done in [this code](https://github.com/commontk/CTK/blob/master/Libs/Widgets/ctkCollapsibleGroupBox.cpp). The issue I'm running into is that my overridden `drawPrimitive()` function isn't being called at all for QGroupBox widgets... but it is called for other widgets with that same proxy style applied! Looking in the `drawComplexControl()` function of [qcommonstyle.cpp](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qcommonstyle.cpp.html), the `CC_GroupBox` case is calling

```
proxy()->drawPrimitive(PE_IndicatorCheckBox, &box, p, widget);
```

to draw the checkbox, so I don't understand why my overridden function isn't running.

I'm not really sure how to go about debugging this since I can't step into the C++ code to see what is actually being called. Could anyone offer any suggestions that might help me figure out why my overridden `drawPrimitive()` isn't getting called?

**Update 2:**

I've solved the mystery of why my overridden `drawPrimitive()` isn't getting called - it's because my application uses a root-level style sheet, which causes the `QStyleSheetStyle` to be used as the active style for widgets. `QStyleSheetStyle` directly calls its own `drawPrimitive()` method for `CC_GroupBox` rather than calling `proxy()->drawPrimitive()` - this seems like a bug to me, and in fact [this Qt bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68671) states that style sheets don't mix well with `QProxyStyle`. I'm going to try to move away from using style sheets.

eyllanesc's technique works with the Fusion style so I have accepted his answer, but it is incompatible with other styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to implement a QProxyStyle:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class GroupBoxProxyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def subControlRect(self, control, option, subControl, widget):
        ret = super(GroupBoxProxyStyle, self).subControlRect(
            control, option, subControl, widget
        )
        if (
            control == QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_GroupBox
            and subControl == QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_GroupBoxLabel
            and widget.isCheckable()
        ):
            r = self.subControlRect(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_GroupBox,
                option,
                QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_GroupBoxCheckBox,
                widget,
            )
            ret.adjust(r.width(), 0, 0, 0)
        return ret

    def drawComplexControl(self, control, option, painter, widget):
        is_group_box = False
        if control == QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_GroupBox and widget.isCheckable():
            option.subControls &= ~QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_GroupBoxCheckBox
            is_group_box = True
        super(GroupBoxProxyStyle, self).drawComplexControl(
            control, option, painter, widget
        )
        if is_group_box and widget.isCheckable():
            opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem()
            opt.rect = self.proxy().subControlRect(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_GroupBox,
                option,
                QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_GroupBoxCheckBox,
                widget,
            )
            opt.state = QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Children
            opt.state |= (
                QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Open
                if widget.isChecked()
                else QtWidgets.QStyle.State_None
            )
            self.drawPrimitive(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.PE_IndicatorBranch, opt, painter, widget
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    style = GroupBoxProxyStyle(app.style())
    app.setStyle(style)

    w = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(title="Exclusive Radio Buttons")
    w.setCheckable(True)
    vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    for text in ("Radio button 1", "Radio button 2", "Radio button 3"):
        radiobutton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(text)
        vbox.addWidget(radiobutton)
    vbox.addStretch(1)
    w.setLayout(vbox)

    w.resize(320, 240)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

The conversion of the [code](https://github.com/commontk/CTK/blob/master/Libs/Widgets/ctkCollapsibleGroupBox.cpp) provided by the OP to Python is as follows:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class GroupBoxProxyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def drawPrimitive(self, element, option, painter, widget):
        if element == QtWidgets.QStyle.PE_IndicatorCheckBox and isinstance(
            widget, QtWidgets.QGroupBox
        ):
            super().drawPrimitive(
                QtWidgets.QStyle.PE_IndicatorArrowDown
                if widget.isChecked()
                else QtWidgets.QStyle.PE_IndicatorArrowRight,
                option,
                painter,
                widget,
            )
        else:
            super().drawPrimitive(element, option, painter, widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    style = GroupBoxProxyStyle(app.style())
    app.setStyle(style)

    w = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(title="Exclusive Radio Buttons")
    w.setCheckable(True)
    vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    for text in ("Radio button 1", "Radio button 2", "Radio button 3"):
        radiobutton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(text)
        vbox.addWidget(radiobutton)
    vbox.addStretch(1)
    w.setLayout(vbox)

    w.resize(320, 240)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Awesome! This seems like it will work great. I haven't gotten the alignment of the label and expander quite right yet but I'll play around with it some more. Also, adding QStyle.State_MouseOver will highlight the expander when you're hovering over it (still need to figure out how to detect that case).

Comment: Looks like I spoke a bit too soon - I've run into some issues overriding methods of QProxyStyle. I've updated the original question with my current progress.

Comment: @Gumgo I do not understand you, in your update you show a code different from mine, have you tried my code? Did my code work? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: @Gumgo The questions I mentioned in my previous comment because in your update you do not indicate anything about my answer, you only point out a new answer based on a code of the year 2013 that probably works with Qt4, and it is not compatible with Qt

Comment: I did try your code and it almost worked but I was having issues with the label text placement - adjusting the rect didn't seem to shift the text over properly. Also, the union of the checkbox and the text rects gets masked out when drawing the groupbox's frame, and disabling the checkbox entirely would prevent that portion from being included in the mask, which would result in extra frame line overlapping the expander icon. It seems a bit cleaner if I can figure out how to replace the checkbox itself with the expander, but if I can't then I will still mark your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @Gumgo When you indicate that a solution does not work you should point out just the above, and not just say that it did not work. Now I ask you 2 things: 1) an image of the problem that you indicate that my code generates. 2) You could provide an MCVE, this I ask because since you see in my images it works correctly but so that you have another code so you would have to analyze that code to see where the problem is.

Comment: Here is what appears when I copy-paste the code you've provided: https://imgur.com/a/lG4y5J1

I'm setting the proxy style on the widget directly rather than at application level so there is a slight difference in our code there, but I can post my version if you think it could contribute to the visual discrepancy. However, I assume it's due to differences in the default styles used on our OSes. Replacing the checkbox with an expander directly in drawPrimitive() feels like it would be slightly more resilient to base style differences, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Gumgo Provide the MCVE please. Also what style do you have on your computer? what is the output in `print(QtWidgets.QApplication.style().objectName())`?

Comment: `print(QtWidgets.QApplication.style().objectName())` produces an empty string. The code from your post works as an MCVE as it produces [this](https://imgur.com/a/l30hoMS) on my machine.

Comment: @Gumgo what is the output: `print(QtWidgets.QApplication.style().metaObject().className())`?

Comment: Making both of those calls near the beginning of the code you provided results in `windowsvista` and `QWindowsVistaStyle`.

Comment: @Gumgo Have you set the QGroupBox in `setCheckable(True)`?

Comment: I have, the code I'm using is the same as the block you posted. Out of interest, what is the result of `QtWidgets.QApplication.style().objectName()` and `QtWidgets.QApplication.style().metaObject().className()` on your machine? Neither `QWindowsVistaStyle` nor any of its superclasses until `QCommonStyle` modify the `drawComplexControl()` behavior for `CC_GroupBox`, perhaps your machine's style does? That would explain the discrepancies between our results.

Comment: @Gumgo In my case, I use fusion-QFusionStyle, since it is a style that all OSs have.

Comment: When I switch to fusion style I get the same results as you! So that mystery is solved. I would still like to try to get `drawPrimitive()` overriding working because that seems more likely to work with multiple different base styles, so I will play around with that some more, but I will mark your answer as accepted in any case.

Comment: @Gumgo Each style has its own logic, so there is no single solution for all. You should analyze the source code and see how each style works. In my case I use the Fusion style because it is agnostic to the OS.